# Oracle PLSQL Alter/Drop Attributes of Object Type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am new to Oracle PLSQL and have to Alter an Object Type. I´ve made many mistakes with the data types of the new Columns, so I had to drop them and altered them a second time.

For example, I did this:

```
ALTER TYPE testObjectType ADD ATTRIBUTE (Prename VARCHAR2(50))

ALTER TYPE testObjectType DROP ATTRIBUTE Prename

ALTER TYPE testObjectType ADD ATTRIBUTE (Prename VARCHAR2(50 CHAR))
```

Now below the "Create or Replace" - Code of the Object there are many lines of code about adding & dropping Attributes. I´ve to try to simply delete this lines but the changes don't work at all. How can I tidy up my Object-Type? (I'm using Oracle SQL Developer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset it so it is no longer treated as an evolved type:

```
alter type testobjecttype reset;
```

Then you can rebuild it with:

```
create or replace type testobjecttype as object
( prename varchar2(50 char) );
```

(plus any other attributes etc it should have).

btw there isn't much point naming database objects in CamelCase as the database ignores it, and schema browsers will just list it in uppercase (because that's how the dictionary stores names), which can become hard to read without word separators. (And shouldn't it be `TestObjectType` anyway?) There is a better case for it in naming program variables, although they are case-insensitive as well, so it's probably simplest and cleanest to just code in lowercase.